# Site Width Expanding too much

Tags: jquery, html, css

I designed a website on my local server and it was of perfect width.

I uploaded it on live server and made some changes to design.

Now there is scroll bar on bottom of the page and site is expanding at least 1000 pixels even after there is no content there.

I have been scratching my head for over two hours from where this width is coming from. I have tried inspect element on each and every block level element but not sure what is causing this weird issue.

Here is the url:
http://new.thearena.com.pk/index.php

Ahmar

Comment: Post some code that is relevant to your issue please

Comment: I don't know what is causing this. So no idea what code to post ?

Comment: Then you need to isolate the problem better, we can't be expected to go through your site and debug your code for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your footer navigation. In your CSS (dstyle.css, line 232) you have

```
.fs-navigation span {
  text-indent: -90000px;
}
```

Add `overflow: hidden;` to solve the issue.